# Benefits/uses of non-base 10 number systems?

Tags: notation, philosophy, number-systems

For reference, I'm studying math and anthropology at university, and I've been dying to find some overlap of math theory and ethnomathematics (math uses/tools/systems/etc in other cultures). I'm getting to the point in my math education where we're incorporating the binary system into proof work as well, and it's gotten me thinking about different base systems in other cultures.

Some examples include vigesimal systems with a base 20, sexagesimal systems with base 60, and duodecimal systems with a base 12.

While the binary system is a helpful tool for Y/N, either-or categorization and organization, (and hexadecimal systems as well) has there been any other cases of non-base 10 systems being used in the math world? Be it to aid with visualization, strengthen proofs/theories/etc, or to build upon current subfields?

Comment: Not sure what all you're looking for here... but imperial measurements can have some (*annoying*) non-base10 conversions.  The base60 used in babylon and the like were useful as it is easily divisible by a large number of natural numbers.  $60$ is divisible by $1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60$.  If looking for uses in proofs... many of the more advanced proofs in several topics are base agnostic... but you do get some elementary proofs that can benefit, like proving $k^n-1$ is divisble by $k-1$ is particularly easy when considering the number written in base $k$.

Comment: ((1)) There are certain "theorems" where Proof involves base 3 , sometimes with "Digits" +1 , 0 & -1 , which give "Symmetric" arguments easily. ((2)) Electrical / Communication / Electronic Engineering techniques sometimes use tristate logic in Signalling / Switching / Encoding.

Comment: You might find something of interest in Knuth's *Seminumerical Algorithms*. General bases are also of interest in questions of diophantine approximation - google for "metric diophantine approximation".

Comment: Base $\phi$ is used because $\phi^2=\phi+1$ implies any integer can be written as a terminating series of 1s and 0s in base-$\phi$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base